# What should I do with my legendary bear pelt?

Tags: red-dead-redemption-2

I killed a bear and got a legendary bear pelt from it. According to some help text, I can use this to craft some special outfit. But right now, that large package is simply taking up space on the back of my horse.

What can I do with the legendary bear pelt? And is there a way to store it somehow, so that I can free up the space on my horse?

Answer (score 11):

Sell to trapper. He will hold it until you have other items needed to craft items in a set.

Comment: The pelt is used in the Bear Hunter Outfit, sold/crafted at the Trapper, but you must sell him the pelt first.

Answer (score 7):

If you drop it on the ground and abandon it a pop up appears and says it will be at the Fence or Trapper for crafting.